# How can I set the baseurl for Jekyll via command line?

Tags: jekyll

When I want to test something local I use

```
baseurl: "http://localhost/blog/_site"
```

and when I deploy the website I use

```
baseurl: "http://martinthoma.github.io"
```

Changing `_config.yml` every time is not a solution, because I would like to use a makefile like this:

Local testing:

```
make test
```

Deployment:

```
make deploy
```

So my question is: How can I set the baseurl for Jekyll via command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably use a separate _config_prod.yml for production. When you build Jekyll, you can use the `--config` flag and pass `_config_prod.yml` to it as an option.

Check it out: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options

I imagine this would be easy enough to put into your makefile.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the `-b` or `--baseurl` flag, as shown in the documentation [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options).